# What does the bitwise AND operator & do in this code snippet?

Tags: c, bitwise-and

Please help to solve this problem and explain the logic.
I don't know how the & operator is working here.

```
void main() {
   int a = -1;
   static int count;
   while (a) {
      count++;
      a &= a - 1;
   }
   printf("%d", count);
}
```

Comment: count should be initialized by the way

Comment: What is the problem? What is the answer you expect?

Comment: Looks an awful lot like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer/109036#109036

Comment: @Andrew It is good programming practice to initialize it, but strictly speaking it isn't required for the program to work as expected.

Comment: @Lundin So i've posted the comment, not an answer

Answer (score 5):

If you are referring to

```
a&=a-1;
```

then it is a bitwise and operation of a and a-1 copied into a afterwards.

Edit:
As copied from Tadeusz A. Kadłubowski in the comment:

```
a = a & (a-1);
```

Comment: It pretty much means the same as `a = a & (a-1);`

Comment: @Tadeusz copied and attributed and upvoted your comment, thnx

Comment: it might be important to notice that for some values of `a` this expressions might not be equivalent. Consider `#define a (++b)` for some other variable `b`. A minor clarification just in case the OP was a CS student learning intricacies of C.

Comment: When using `#define` all bets are off. You can't be sure anything means anything. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The expression `a&=a-1;` clears the least significant bit (rightmost 1) of `a`. The code counts the number of bits in `a` (-1 in this case).

Starting from

```
a = -1 ; // 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 32bits signed integer
```

The code outputs `32` on an 32 bit integer configuration.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is the [bitwise and operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

The operation

```
a&=a-1;
```

which is same as:

```
a = a & a-1;
```

clears the least significant bit of `a`.

So your program effectively is calculating the number of bits set in `a`.

And since `count` is declared as `static` it will automatically initialized to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

you have count uninitialized

should be

```
static int count=0;
```

operator & is called AND http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

Comment: The C standard guarantees that static variables are initialized to zero if the programmer didn't init them explicitly. Regardless, good practice is that the program either initialize them explicitly or assign a value to them before using them.

Comment: I tried to contradict you on this above and realised my mistake after looking at the C specification. The relevant portion is 6.7.8.10 if anyone else happens to be looking.